# Calculating distance between left edge of div and left edge of viewport for horizontal parallax

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

When I query the left position of the container, it returns static numbers even while I scroll. Is this because there is no x-scroll enabled? If so, how should I restructure my code?

The jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0xcbmrjo/

And the js:

```
const body = document.querySelector("body")
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper")
const bodyHeight = function () {
  body.style.height = wrapper.offsetWidth - (window.innerWidth - window.innerHeight) +'px'
}
bodyHeight ()
window.addEventListener ("resize", bodyHeight)

document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  let scroll = window.pageYOffset
  wrapper.style.left = `${-1 * scroll}px`

  const leftViewport = window.pageXOffset
  const midViewport = leftViewport + (window.innerWidth/2)

  const containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container")
  containers.forEach(container => {
    const leftContainer = container.offsetLeft
    const midContainer = leftContainer + (container.offsetWidth/2)
    const distanceToContainer = midViewport - midContainer
  })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN, `offsetLeft` reads from the `offsetParent` property, which is a "reference to the element which is the closest (nearest in the containment hierarchy) positioned ancestor element" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent). In our case, we reposition the `.wrapper` element, which takes all the children (`.container` elements) with it so that the `.container` elements maintain constant offset relative to their immediate ancestor, hence the "static" offsets.